# Google Analytics on multiple independent sites

Tags: tracking, google-analytics

I want to use Google Analytics to monitor two completely separate websites.  I have read a number of resources about setting up GA for multiple domains and subdomains, but they all seem to be set up for sites that are related somehow.

To be specific, my first GA account was set up to track my account at Shapeways. To set up tracking on Shapeways, I set up my own GA account and supplied my tracking number to Shapeways. My default GA website is something like shapeways.com/my_shapeways_pages...

I want to set up tracking for a demo project I have set up as a free subdomain, with an address like mypage.atwebpages.com.  I tried to create a new profile in my GA account, and exclude traffic from shapeways.com, but this doesn't really work.  I test my GA setup by opening pages from both of my sites, and looking at what shows up in GA's real-time reporting.  I see active pages from both sites in my GA reporting.

Is it possible to do what I am asking?  I want to see separate reporting from each site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and quite easy.

You login, go to the **Admin** page, which should say *Account Administration* upon entering the page.

Then, you just click on the **+ New Account** button.

*OR*

You can add a different site to a current account by clicking on that account and then clicking on the **+New Property** button.

Then, the rest of it is just like you've done before.

Comment: Thank you, I was mixing up profiles and properties.  It still took a few attempts to set things up right; the properties kept affecting each other somehow.  I ended up deleting all my properties, willingly giving up my old tracking data.  I then set up each property separately, with their own default profiles.